# Intellij IDEA includes other module that is already included by Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I've got a 2-module Intellij project that is Maven-based and is organized like this:

```
MyAppProject
    --->MyAppDomain (builds a JAR)
    --->MyAppWAR (builds a WAR, including the JAR above)
```

I can build the project using Maven, and the resulting WAR contains MyAppDomain.JAR as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyAppDomain</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This WAR works in Tomcat.  However, if I build it using Intellij Idea Ultimate's neat Tomcat integration, WAR fails with this error (formatted for readability):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/data-context.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Conflicting persistence unit definitions for name 'caPersistenceUnit': 
file:/C:/JavaSoftware/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/MyApplication/WEB-INF/lib/MyAppDomain.jar, file:/C:/JavaSoftware/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/MyApplication/WEB-INF/lib/MyAppDomain-1.0.0.jar
```

So, it appears that IDEA is including the Maven-specified JAR (MyAppDomain-1.0.0.jar)  and also including it's own version of this JAR (MyAppDomain.jar) containing all the same files.

I have searched in vain for a way to turn this off in Intellij IDEA - does anybody know how to stop this behavior (including co-resident projects)?

Comment: u checked inside the war file , that there exists two jars for MyAppDomain with different names ??

Comment: Yep, they're both there.   See below for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find out how to turn this behavior OFF, but I found a workaround that builds the WAR correctly.

```
  1. Select "Run -> Edit Configurations" from the menu. 
  2. Select your"Tomcat Server" job. 
  3. Click the "Deployment" tab. 
  4. At the bottom, where it says "Before Launch:  Another Configuration,"  delete the "Make" option. 
  5. Click the "+" (plus) sign and select your Maven Build task to add it to the "Before Launch" list.
```

By doing this, Intellij will use the Maven build task you have set up to create your WAR, instead of using its own "Make" command.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountered the same problem in IDEA.

This problem was occured because you have ran `mvn clean package(or install)` in IDEA before you start Tomcat.

The `mvn clean package` will generates Maven-specified JAR (MyAppDomain-1.0.0.jar), but start 
Tomcat will generates JAR without version spefified (MyAppDomain.jar).That is the problem you have the two same jars in your classpath.

To solve this problem,**just manually run `mvn clean` in your IDEA before you start Tomcat** if you have ran `mvn clean package` ever.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this issue too. The generated war contained two versions of the same dependency (which is a module), and that was causing problems.

I had to edit my tomcat launch configuration in IntelliJ:

1. **Edit launch configurations**
2. Click on your tomcat configuration and then go to **Deployment** tab
3. On the bottom of the window, add a "**Before launch**" task clicking on the plus icon
4. Select **Run Maven Goal**
5. Write "clean" as command line and accept
   [image: maven goal clean]
6. Move the task to the top, before Build